# The title border is partially hidden by the page header

Tags: discussion, design

I'm exposed to the interface for the first time, and I have this strange feeling that the page is incomplete somehow.  After scratching my head and considering the layout and design, I realized that the question title border is partly hidden by the drop-shadowed page header.

- It looks incomplete - like I should be able to scroll up under the page header
- Alternately it appears to be part of the page header (centered with the site title and menus) but has little to no relation to the question which is off-center

The design otherwise looks great, but it just *itches* a little bit.

So my question is:

- Am I totally crazy for having this feeling when I visit?
- Am I alone in this (relatively minor) annoyance?

Comment: +1: You're not totally crazy :-)

Answer (score 3):

I say you give it some time. I feel to have a complete 4 sided box would make the site overly boxy, considering we have quite a few boxes on the sidebar already.

Comment: I don't  have a problem with it.